# How to revert multiple merges in Git

Tags: git, merge, commit, revert

I need to revert a branch to a previous point. 
As you can see in the following picture the branch has multiple commits and merges done. 
I need to revert this to the "fixing" commit.

[image: branch history]

So i tried:

```
git revert --no-commit fixingHashCode..HEAD
```

but the it throws an error:

> error: commit fixingHashCode is a merge but no -m option was given.
>   fatal: revert failed

Next i used:

```
git revert --no-commit fixingHashCode..HEAD -m 3
```

And a error was reported again:

> error: mainline was specified but commit fixingHashCode is not a merge.
>   fatal: revert failed

How can i acheive this?

Comment: Do you want to add one or more new commits that undo the changes since `fixing`, or do you want to change the history, pretending that all the red and blue commits never existed? (Since the history is already published, changing it would not be a good idea.)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want undo the commits ands mergers, not erase the wrong commits if possible

Answer (score -1):

If it's an urgent question I guess you can.just revert the commits and jump one commit backwards on HEAD on the tree.