# How to revert multiple pull request merges all at once and preserve history

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request, revert

I have a case where the Github repo master currently has a series of individual pull requests that have already been merged into master. I want to revert say the last 20 of those pull request merges but do it from the command line and preserve history.

A similar question was marked as duplicate [revert multiple merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119462/how-to-revert-multiple-merges-in-git)

However the answers given as already existing do not really deal with the specific question of what happens when everything you want to revert came from a series of pull requests which are all merges. Using the -m option with git revert is good for one merge at time right? So I think the answer is that there is not a good way (from the command line) to quickly revert a series of individual pull requests that have been merged and preserve history? Please correct me if I am wrong about this. If I have to do one at a time, I might as well just use the Github console and click on revert for each one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to have a single (later) revision where you revert the changes from all those merges, you can do it like this:

```
git checkout <id-of-revision> # use the ID of the revision you would like to get your project back to (in terms of content)
git reset --soft <the-branch> # the branch where we want to add a revision to revert all of that
git commit -m "Reverting"
# If you like the results
git branch -f <the-branch> # move branch pointer to this new revision
git checkout <the-branch>
```

Update:
Nowadays, it's simpler to do with `git restore`

```
git checkout <the-branch>
git restore --worktree --staged --source <id-of-revision> -- .
git commit -m "Reverting"
```

And you are getting to the same place as with the original recipe.

Comment: Nope.... the branch is whatever branch you are working on. master? develop? anything else?

Comment: Ok. So for my application, I used master for <the-branch>, then after the final line above I did a `git checkout -b feature/new-master` then I could push this to the remote and create a pull request for it. That did what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

## Step1

Create a new backup branch first and keep it aside. (backup-branch)
Create a new branch from master or dev wherever you want to revert.(working-branch)

`git revert commitid1`

`git revert commitid2`

`git revert commitid3`....
is the best option.

### dont do `git reset --hard commitid` it will mesh up your indexing.

Reverting is the safe option.

## i have done 180 revert commits.

## Step2

`git log -180 --format=%H --no-merges`
use this command to print all the commit ids alone.

it will ignore the merge commit id.

`commitid1 commitid2 commitid3 .....` it will print like that.

Copy it to sublime ctrl+a -> ctrl +alt + l add

`git revert --no-commit commitid1`

`git revert --no-commit commitid2`

`git revert --no-commit commitid3`

Copy all and paste in the command prompt. All your commits will be reverted. now do a git commit.

Then do git push.
create a merge request to master.

## Step3

**How to verifiy?**

create a new branch (verify-branch).

YOu can verify it by doing a

`git reset -hard commitidX`. This is the commit id to which you need to revert.

`git status` It will give you the number of commits behind the master.

`git push -f`

Now compare this branch with your working-branch by creating a pull request between them. you will see no changes means your working branch successfully reverted back to the version you're looking for.