# Consequence of Git soft reset

Tags: git

I hope someone can help as I'm quite new to git. Lets say I have the following merged PRs on main branch:
A->B->C->D->E-F

I need to get it back to the state it was in at commit C because D E F have issues that need fixing. So I do a soft reset back to C to another branch (to revert D,E,F) and then merge that branch back into main. Now I have commit G that reverts D, E and F.
A->B->C->D->E-F->G

Two questions:

1. Can someone else now easily branch off main, do their work and merge back in without issues.
2. How do I go about fixing the bad commits D E F? Should I make a new branch off master as it is now and redo all the changes?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of things. First, chart should be `A<-B<-C...` because in git children revisions *point* to their parents, not the other way around. Then, if you did a soft reset (`git checkout F; git reset --soft C; git commit -m "reverting"`), then that is not correct. You end up with a revision after C that has the same *content* of F, which is not what you want, right?

Probably what you want to do is rather:

```
git checkout C
git reset --soft F
git commit -m "Reverting to C" 
# this revision we just created has the content of C and its parent is F....
# in other words, it reverts changes introduced by D, E and F
# feel free to set a branch over here push and merge
```

Point questions.

1 - Yes. The general rule is that if you do not rewrite history of the branch, people should be able to work on a branch moving forward. It is when people start rewriting shared branches that things can go nuts. Of course.... this implies that people won't be working on things related to D, E and F. If it's related to those revisions, then conflicts are expected to happen later on given that you are taking those changes back.

2 - Let's assume that each one of them is a feature of its own and does *not* depend on the other 2 broken revisions.... and you want to start working from that first revision.... so, let's say I want to work on E:

```
git checkout -b branchE E # create a feature branch on E
git commit --amend --no-edit # make git believe that this is something that has not been merged yet
git rebase master # rebase on top of master
# now you can continue working so that you get the change working correctly on this branch
.
.
# when you are done with it, push and create a PR and merge.
```

Comment: Thanks @eftshift0. I actually followed your other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766114/how-to-revert-multiple-pull-request-merges-all-at-once-and-preserve-history when doing this. So yes, I did the steps as you mentioned, `git checkout C` etc. 
In response number 2 (rework on bad commits) you say: `git checkout -b branchE E`, I take it 'E' is the commit hash for E?

Comment: Yep, that's it.